# Log::info - Logging user logout in laravel.log

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want add all activities inside my app in the larave.log file.
I was able to add user login inside it but not the logout.

I do that using Laravel 5.8 with a mysql 5 database.

This is code inside HomeController for registering login user loading home view.

```
public function index()
{
    Log::info('Utente collegato: '.Auth::user()->name);
    return view( config('configpath.user_home') );// loading user homepage
}
```

The code below is inside Laravel default LoginController

```
public function userLogout()
{
    Log::info('User '.Auth::user()->name. 'has logged out');
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

With logout I expect to see the message about user logout as in login but I don't see it. Someone can give me an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that code is being executed? try adding a `dd('message')` before the `return` and check if you get 'message'

Comment: Tried it but nothing. I have only logout without a print in the logging file.
This code has not executed.

Comment: Then you should add the log on the proper logout function, check the answer from Florian

Comment: Your logic seems off a bit, as the login log message will be created whenever the user visits his home path at `HomeController@index`.

Answer (score 9):

You can listen for the `Login` and `Logout` event to log the actions. To to so, add the following to the `boot()` method of your `EventServiceProvider`:

```
Event::listen(\Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class, function ($event) {
    \Log::info("User login: {$event->user->name}");
});

Event::listen(\Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout::class, function ($event) {
    \Log::info("User logout: {$event->user->name}");
});
```

Using this method, you don't have to override the existing and framework-provided controller actions.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. To complete this answer, here is the link to the list of events automatically raised by the Laravel framework during the authentication process : https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#events

Comment: Thank you, this code has solved my problem.
Obviously I must improve my knowledge about EventServiceProvider class.
Now the problem is about the datetime because the logger register the events 2 hours less (i.e. in my country is 27 past 12 but my logger register the login event at 27 past 10)
What class edit hour and minutes (datetime) of my logger?

Comment: Normally, the logger logs the time using the `timezone` defined in `config/app.php` (or in the `.env` file with key `APP_TIMEZONE`). The default is `UTC` while you seem to need `Europe/Berlin` for example.

Comment: Ok, I solved also this problem. I have modified 'timezone' in 'config.app' from 'Utc' to 'Europe/Berlin' as reported in PHP 5 timezones and, now, the logger reports right timezone.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Great! Please accept one of the answers if your problem is solved. :)

Comment: That's the correct answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to override the correct method. I think userLogout gets never called from the framework.

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('User '.Auth::user()->email.' has logged out');
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();

    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, the logout route can be changed. But I'd prefer your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a logout method in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{

  Log::info('User '.Auth::user()->email.' has logged out');

  $this->guard()->logout();

  $request->session()->invalidate();

  return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

This method will call on log out if you have set default authentication routes and Log will be added on log out in a laravel.log file.